# Slow query with Entity Framework when using Include with Func predicate

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

Can someone please tell me how to include a `where` clause in a `linq to sql` query when using entity framework with include

I have the following query:

```
var test = this.MyContext.MyData
           .Include("MoreData")
           .Include("EvenMoreData")
           .Where(predicate)
```

Where the predicate is defined as follows:

```
t => t.id == myId
```

The problem is that it does not seem to include the `Where` clause in the SQL query when I check it via SQL Server Profiler which is causing my query to be extremely slow as its returning 450k+ records instead of 7 in my specific example.

Any ideas on how I can include there `where` clause in the query generated by `EF`.

**UPDATE-1:**

Strange but when replacing the predicate variable set as follows:

```
private MyObject Get(Func<MyObject, bool> predicate)

...

this.UnitOfWork.MyObject.Get(t=>t.id == myId);
```

by

```
var test = this.MyContext.MyData
       .Include("MoreData")
       .Include("EvenMoreData")
       .Where(t=>t.id = 1234)
```

The where statement gets included and the data is returned instantly.

Comment: Are foreign keys between MyData, MoreData and EvenMoreData properly set?

Comment: Note this is a simplified example but the foreign keys are set on some of the tables, not all.

Comment: If tables does not have foreign keys, how is it possible join then (which .Include does)?

Comment: I'm not sure but it definitely works it is just slow. I will update my answer in a second as I have found out something interesting but not the solution just yet.

Comment: Without foreign keys it cannot restrict join results and retrieves whole table contents (450k?) -> slow

Comment: where does expect a Expression<Func<T,bool>>, so maybe the additional conversion forces it to evaluate locally?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong about the foreign key but don't think so. How do you explain the comments from the updated answer

Comment: @DevilSuichiro Since changing this to an Expression, my query has gone from taking 29sec to taking under 12ms which is excellent since it is now filtered accordingly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments:

.Where() does expect an `Expression<Func<T,bool>>`, whereas your predicate appears to be of type `Func<T,bool>` . This (presumably) prohibits EF from converting it into a SQL query, meaning it will be evaluated locally (on the underlying ICollection implementation).

On this note, please be aware that WHERE conditions on .Include's do not work as you probably would've anticipated, since the generated SQL will join the two mapped tables and evaluate the condition on the result table, as opposed to joining the mapped table with the reduced result set of the second table. The reason this query runs faster is 1. the DBS may be able to use indices due to the condition and 2. the number of to be materialized rows is lower.